# How to replace text in string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have this particular piece of code, but its not working.

```
text = text.Replace("\xEF\xBF\xBD", "?");
```

Does any one knows how to replace the text `"\xEF\xBF\xBD"` to `"?"` in C# `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer (guessing a bit):**

```
text = text.Replace("\xFFFD", "?");
```

And learn about [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) and [character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), especially [utf-8.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8)

**Long answer:**

Well, do you mean "\xEF\xBF\xBD" literally? That is, a string consisting of these characters:

```
backslash, uppercase latin character E, uppercase latin character F, backslash, uppercase latin character B, uppercase latin character F, backslash, uppercase latin character B, uppercase latin character D
```

Then, the answer would be:

```
text = text.Replace(@"\xEF\xBF\xBD", "?");
```

Or do you sequences of characters which are described by the C# escape sequence "\xEF\xBF\xBD", namely:

```
LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS, INVERTED QUESTION MARK, VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF
```

(which would be displayed as "ï¿½)? Then, the your code would be correct:

```
text = text.Replace("\xEF\xBF\xBD", "?");
```

Or do you  want to replace the **byte** sequence

```
EF BF BD
```

(which could actually be the utf-8 representation of the unicode replacement character, FFFD, which is often displayed as"�")?

This is just a wild guess, but by intuition says you actually want to achieve the latter. Now, a .Net string contains characters, not bytes, but assuming that you have read these bytes e.g. from a file as utf-8, the answer would be:

```
text = text.Replace("\xFFFD", "?");
```

Comment: I was talking about the byte sequence, and not just plain characters values, your answer worked well. But can you please elaborate on why I can't just replace the byte sequence by giving the byte values as I did in the question and why I have to write \xFFFD

Comment: well found the answer from Wikipedia to my comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Specials

Answer (score 15):

You have to escape the backslashes.

```
text = text.Replace("\\xEF\\xBF\\xBD", "?");
```

Alternatively, you can escape the entire string with the @ symbol:

```
text = text.Replace(@"\xEF\xBF\xBD", "?");
```

Comment: Combined both answers.  Give rep to David, as he needs it.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I didn't even know you could combine answers. Very cool.

Comment: This answer may technically correct if you take Priyanks question verbatim, but I don't think he really wants to replace the characters "ï¿½"...

Comment: I wasn't asking on how to escape backslash, I wanted to replace the Unicode sequence.