# Arabic Problem Replace أً with just ا

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

How to replace the alf bel tanween with a normal alf

Comment: Any reason for wanting to use a regex for this?

Comment: You might want to supply some additional contextual information such as how you're storing the string, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bolo's enlightment
after a couple of minutes of searching i did it like that:

```
string s = "";
        foreach (Char c in x)
        {
            if (((int)c).ToString("x").ToLower() != "64b")
                s += c.ToString();

        }
```

**where x is my string**

Like that I excluded the **ARABIC FATHATAN** from the string

Answer (score 5):

I don't know C#, but that's more a UNICODE question.  I would do it by means of [UNICODE normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html), using [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx).

First, normalize to decomposed form.  Next, filter out all characters from the "Mark, Nonspacing" category **[Mn]**.  Finally, normalize back to composed form.

If I see correctly, your glyph is represented in UNICODE by `ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH HAMZA ABOVE` ([U+0623](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0623/index.htm), **[Lo]**) followed by `ARABIC FATHATAN` ([U+064B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/064B/index.htm), **[Mn]**).  The first character decomposes to `ARABIC LETTER ALEF` ([U+0627](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0627/index.htm), **[Lo]**) + `ARABIC HAMZA ABOVE` ([U+0654](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0654/index.htm), **[Mn]**).

Here's the chain of transformations (the first arrow indicates a decomposition, the second – filtering out nonspacing marks, the third – a composition):

```
U+0623 + U+064B → U+0627 + U+0654 + U+064B → U+0627 → U+0627
```

After you decompose, remove all the characters from the **[Mn]** category, and compose back, you're left with `ARABIC LETTER ALEF` only.

Comment: I use this method to remove diacritics from texts written using Latin alphabet.  Next, I need to handle a couple of exceptions, like `Ł`, but the described method covers most of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this project which provides examples of how to replace unicode characters in strings: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/FontGlyphSet.aspx

See also:

- [How to replace text in string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917250/how-to-replace-text-in-string-in-c)
- [Manipulating both unicode and ASCII character set in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602051/manipulating-both-unicode-and-ascii-character-set-in-c)